# Why will some YouTube videos not load in any browser on my system?

Tags: video, internet-connection, youtube

For an estimated 20% of all YouTube videos I try to watch on one of my computers, I cannot get them to buffer at all. I will get the loading spinner, until about a minute later the player will say that "an error occured, please try again later."

I have ruled out a lot of possible causes and don't know where else to look.

- It's not a general YouTube or video playback problem. I can watch the majority of YouTube videos fine. It's certain ones that I can't get to play no matter how often I retry. I haven't had any problems with video playback on other sites, although I rarely watch video outside of YouTube.
- It's not a browser or extension problem. The videos that play fine, play in all browsers. Those that don't, won't load in any browser I have installed. In particular, I tried Firefox 32.0.3, Chrome 44.0.2403.130, and Opera 31.0.1889.99. I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise SP-1.
- It's not a Flash player problem. The affected videos won't load in either the Flash player or the HTML5 player.
- It's not an issue with a particular stream. None of the offered stream qualities will load, while for working videos, all of them load. (In particular, there's no difference between regular and DASH streams.)
- It's not an issue with particular videos themselves. The same videos work fine if I play them from any other device. Also, on some other day it might be different videos that will not play, while previously broken ones work again.
- It's not an ISP or connection issue. The computer in question is a corporate one, set up identically to other computers in the room which share the same connection. Other computers play all the videos fine without buffering problems. Mine seems to be the only one affected. There are no active software firewalls or local hosts files, and I'm using the same DNS as everybody else.
- It doesn't seem to be a cache issue. I cleared all local data of the Flash player and all browsers. The problem persists, and still always for the same videos.
- It's not a temporary issue, this has been going on for the 18 months I've used this computer.
- Incidentally, I can also not get to any of the streams by using stream downloader plug-ins. They will get 0 Bytes and just time out.

What could be other possible causes for this issue, or what should I try doing to narrow in on the problem? My current workaround is to RDP to a different computer and watch the problematic video there, which is not the most comfortable of solutions.

Example for a video currently playing fine: [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UznHTBZIa8E)
Example for a video currently not playing: [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL3BlDYWmRk)

**Some more observations:** I noticed that on the pages of those videos that won't play, also none of the thumbnails of related videos will load. The browser status bar shows that there is no response from `s.youtube.com` nor `s.ytimg.com`. As before, though, on pages of other videos, both the stream and the thumbnails are served fine from the same servers. After a few hours, the affected video pages will be different ones.

Comment: Example links ?

Comment: Upvote for trying lots of things and letting us know ;)

Comment: Thanks :) I added two example links, although now I definitely confirmed that it's not always the same videos that won't play. One that didn't work yesterday now works fine (the computer wasn't rebooted, I didn't even close the browser in between). I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The same thing rarely happens here too , like 2% of the time (2 videos out of 100). "please try again later" more like forget about it later :-) What if it is at thier end the server sees these requests over and over again be it working or retrying to buffer (fast connection), and it is blocking further requests for a while on thier end?  That type of thing would not be the first time where "trying later" works.

Comment: @Psycogeek That at some point it's YouTube blocking the requests would make a lot of sense, considering how seemingly nothing I do on my end makes a difference. That would still leave the question though, why does it only happen to me? About 20 people work with the same setups and connection here, and from talking to them, I seem to be the only one this happens to, at least this frequently...

Comment: Why that often. some browser reading ahead more?  Here i have observed that when hopping fast from video to video (html5), it is one thing that causes IE11 to leave a leftover piece of itself. Once i even had 2 videos stacked on top of eachother (wrongly) playing at the same time.  Could be a clue resides in the resource monitor , in the number of connections to them?  Are your viewing patterns more aggressive and more likely to jump off a video that sucks quick to another, than those you compare to?  Un-paused videos continuing to buffer, videos going that you arent even viewing,, even show.

Comment: I was considering this for a while, and while it's true that I tend to switch between videos rather quickly, and occasionally even open many of them at once in tabs, this does not seem to be the trigger. I hadn't visited YouTube all day, and wanted to view one video in the evening, and the issue occured again…

Comment: Is this Internet Explorer, Firefox, or Chrome?  Have you tried using Ccleaner?  One of the options is to compact and clean out compact the databases (Sqlte)..  OK..  Let's say for the sake of argument, this is all OK..  When was the last time you did a CHKDSK from your command line?  OK..  What about Chrome or Firefox using HTML5 instead of Flash?

Comment: You mentioned that the computer in question is set up the same as others in the same room, but can you provide a bit more information about it? Make and model would be helpful, as would the amount of RAM installed. Also, have you tried the [Youtube video playback troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/youtube/checklist/3480866?hl=en)?

Comment: Researching this issue, it seems that Its the SP1 that has the issues when dealing with streaming videos.  In the following post
http://www.esecurityplanet.com/patches/article.php/3928181/Some-Users-Having-Problems-with-Windows-7-SP1.htm
others seem to be having the same issue you are having.  If you go to the link I posted, read the post by Aaron.  Specifically "By Aaron  |  March 7, 2012 at 4:50 am".  He talks about how his streaming video working, then he installs SP1 and all streaming video starts failing.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Leptonator: It's the same on any browser. I tested FF, Chrome, IE, Opera and Vivaldi. It also doesn't depend on whether the HTML5 or Flash player are loaded. It's in fact not just the video that doesn't load on the pages in question, but also thumbnails of related videos, user avatars, etc., and the AJAX-based video rating or expansion of the description area doesn't work either. All of this works on other video pages that aren't currently affected.

Comment: @boot13: They're custom-built, and the hardware depends on when somebody started their job here. With same setup, I mostly meant connectivity to the network. My office mate started around the same time as me though and our setups are identical: i7-3770K with 32GB RAM and Win7 Enterprise x64. Thank you for the troubleshooter link – I went through it before though, and nothing made a difference.

Comment: @Dale: Thanks for the link! The problems seem to be unrelated though. Nothing freezes and the system isn't otherwise affected. The streams don't even get as far as starting playback – the HTTP requests themselves time out, and as I have found out since posting, not just for the video but also images etc. on the same video's page. While all of this happens and no playback is possible, I can open a related video link in a different tab and that will play fine, while every element on the other page still times out.

Comment: I would start looking at OS - Other than Windows.  If you have 100% surety that you do not have malware/spyware/background task that is killing your connection.  You must do some troubleshooting!!  What about LINUX?  What about Windows 10?  What about your ISP?   Ever since I went with Windows 10 and LINUX Mint, I have been pretty happy.  Something seems to be at "fault" here.  Even using your iPhone or Android Phone is able to replicate or duplicate your issue?

Comment: I ran into this problem not long ago and never did find a solution. I finally assumed it was related to lack of physical RAM (not a problem in your case), which I couldn't do anything about (it was a very old PC) and ended up replacing the computer. Not much help for you, obviously, but I hope you get it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Given the information you've provided, you seem like a fairly competent person and simply need a little direction in how to troubleshoot this issue next, so I'll do just that. Normally, I'd add a comment and ask what I'm about to ask, then give an answer based on your response, but I think we can skip the former.

The only option you have available is to see exactly what is happening to the TCP connection as it fails. There are a couple ways to do this, ranging in complexity and detail. Given that you don't need a whole lot of detail, I'd recommend that you download and install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), which should provide enough information for you to narrow down what is causing this to happen. However, there are a few things to keep in mind.

1. You said this is a corporate computer, so I'm assuming you're using
   some version of Windows and have local admin access to it so you can
   install new software.
2. After installing Fiddler, you'll need to configure it to decrypt
   HTTPS sessions as YouTube (like most modern websites), defaults to
   HTTPS. If you can't figure out how to do this, use Google. I'm
   certain there is, ironically, a YouTube video showing you how to do
   this. In the off-chance that it is one of this videos that won't
   load, there's likely written instructions too.
3. You may have to install and configure a browser extension for it to
   start picking up HTTP(S) data from your browser.
4. Pay attention to the status code of the requests for the videos that
   do not load. That will help tell you if the conversation is dropping
   immediately, if it's the remote server dropping the connection, or
   something else all together.
5. Past Fiddler, the next best utility you could install would be
   [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), but it is a lot more complex and may be too much for
   you to navigate without help. Also, running it while on your
   company's corporate network may be a (serious) network security
   violation. You have been warned.

Lastly, if this is happening regardless of browser or network, that tells you that it is something specific to either the computer or your account (assuming you're logged into YouTube on both browsers). To rule out various possibilities, you could try creating another user account on the computer and log into it to see if this still happens. You could disable any firewall software/services that are running in the background. There's probably more you could do, but those are the two things that come to mind first. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructions! What Fiddler tells me is that on affected video pages, all HTTP(S) requests to, among others, `s.youtube.com`, `s.ytimg.com` or subdomains of `googlevideo.com` return a `502 Bad Gateway` status after about 30 seconds. If I'm interpreting that correctly, it would suggest the source of the problem lies beyond my own computer, somewhere into the network infrastructure of the company, wouldn't it? Maybe some failed caching attempts somewhere, although it wouldn't explain why only I seem to be affected (then again, my sample size isn't huge).

Comment: Hey Daniel, take a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=502+Bad+Gateway+s.youtube.com,+s.ytimg.com+site:productforums.google.com. This doesn't necessarily indicate an issue with your company's network infrastructure.

Comment: Also, http://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2013/aug/01/502-bad-gateway-error has some useful troubleshooting steps worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and found a workaround.

When a video does not a play click the 'next' button (between play and volume) and the next video works. Let it play for 3-4 seconds then go back in the browser then the previous video that was not working earlier will also start working.

I'm not on a corporate network and this happened on my home PC.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to fix YouTube videos not load in browser.

1. Release storage space
2. Check your connection speed
3. Update your browser

However, I prefer to use AmoyShare AnyUTube downloader. It is a free YouTube video downloader, workable on Windows, Mac and Android. AnyUTube offers free and safe videos. It is easy for you to download videos on it either with a link or with a video name. Before downloads, you see video files in different formats, sizes and qualities. You can also preview the video without ads.

Comment: check the link here: https://www.amoyshare.com/anyutube/